# How do I setup a banner to showup only in determined page - OPENX

Tags: php, tags, ads, banner, openx

I Have a website about soccer news. And, I would like to show a banner only when a page is requested. Like, I have a page responsible to show information about a club or team. If my visitor choose a Real Madri´s information page (for example) I would like to show a related banner, and, when my visitor goes to Barcelona´s page, I should show other banner.
the site: www.horabola.com (its in portuguese only)

Comment: How is the content of the pages determined? Is it hard coded into the pages or is it fetched from a db? Need more information here...

Comment: Soccer news, hopefully it is not hard coded ahaha

Comment: @Niklas -> its by a get variable named ID, wich is the team ID on database´s table

Comment: @Connor Smith -> not at all.. its just the first time I use the opENX

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

After creating a banner, you just have to change the banner´s delivery options.
In my case, I added **"delivery limitation"** type **"Site Page URL"** mode **"contains"** and then I just set a team name to the browser so it shows up only in that team's page!